# Drupal Cron - help required in setting monthly and weekly cron

Tags: php, drupal-7, cron

I am new to drupal and waht to have weekly and monthly cron.

I found hook_cron for this which will execute when drupal cron get executed.

I found hook_cronapi also which accents parameter 
`'rule' => '*/2 * * *', // Run this job every day at 3am.`

Want to know what id hook_cronapi and how its works.

Please help me achieving this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core cron in drupal works as everytime it is executed it runs through all hook_crons and executes them.

If you want to have one cron that should execute weekly, and one monthly you can install [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module which will let you to set different settings for every different hook_cron implementation.
These settings are set either by hook_cronapi, or through Cron Settings in admin interface(which is very easy and straightforward).

Comment: ok that means "hook_cronapi" is specific to "Elysia Cron module". It is not drupal core function?

Comment: No it is not a core function. I think other cron modules such as https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron also use it.